# Make the clicked link color stays

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have been trying to make when the link is clicked, the color is stays there, not only when the link is clicked by the mouse (if the mouse lose focus on the link, the color will revert back to the normal state).

Something like this site when you want to ask the question, the color stays on the ask the question tab.

Here is the code sample on JSFiddle that I have trying to:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="parentExample" style="display: block;">
  <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="uiMenuList">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <li id="childExample">
        <a id="uiMenuText" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" runat="server">First Menu</a>
        <a id="uiMenuText" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" runat="server">Second Menu</a>
        <a id="uiMenuText" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" runat="server">Third Menu</a>
      </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document.ready(function() {
  var $h3s = $('li').click(function() {
    $h3s.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
}));
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
  background: none;
  color: #FFC000;
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#parentExample li#childExample a {
  background: none;
  color: black;
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#parentExample li#childExample a:hover {
  background: none;
  color: red;
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#parentExample li#childExample a:active {
  background: none;
  color: #FFC000;
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#parentExample li#childExample a:selected {
  background: none;
  color: #FFC000;
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Here is the example of the above code:
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzwwrsca/)

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Your setup is incorrect. Your code should be `$(function() {
  var $h3s = $('li').click(function() {
  console.log($h3s);
    $h3s.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
` and set the site to load jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give `!important`  as you want to override css using `class` over `id`.  
Because `id` has more **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** than `class`

```
.active {
  background: none !important;
  color: #FFC000 !important;
  border: 0px !important;
  margin-top: -3px !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  margin-left: auto !important;
}
```

And you can not use `$h3` variable like this to make click event.

And you should add and remove class to anchor tag.

If you want to use variable then you can use like following:

```
var h3s = $('li a');
   $('li a').click(function() {
    h3s.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
```

And don't forgot to include JQuery plugins.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzwwrsca/2/)**

Comment: @ketan You mention specificity and provide `!important` as the solution, that seems wrong. @Fuhans, you should try using less ID selectors for your styles and more classes. Exactly because they are less specific and easier to override. Plus, adding `!important` to generic class like `.active` will make your life only harder because of specificity.

Answer (score 2):

try this way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('li a').click(function() {
    $('li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

change your css class position.

like

```
#parentExample li#childExample a {
  background: none;
  color: black;
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#parentExample li#childExample a:hover {
  background: none;
  color: red;
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#parentExample li#childExample a:active {
  background: none;
  color: #FFC000;
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#parentExample li#childExample a:selected {
  background: none;
  color: #FFC000;
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#parentExample li#childExample a.active {
      background: none;
      color: #FFC000;
      border: 0px;
      margin-top: -3px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mzwwrsca/3/

Comment: Hi, even though I have tried this solution, it didn't work, the accepted answer is works for me.

Thanks anyway

Comment: why to use important.